# Bootstrap split button dropdown not styled properly using default styles?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a bug in the bootstrap CSS? I am trying to use the default bootstrap dropdown menu with the split button, but the down-arrow button to the side is much shorter than the actual menu.

I thought this was some overlapping style issue within my code but I have managed to reproduce this using only the boostrap code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20351/).

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default structure of a dropdown uses an unordered list (UL) and you're also missing the `caret` class.

See the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split)

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
</ul>
```

Working Example:

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Split button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
    </li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this happened because of your span tag has class sr-only and this class has fixed width and height 1px in booststrap.css

```
.sr-only {
 position: absolute;
 width: 1px;
 height: 1px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: -1px;
 overflow: hidden;
 clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
 border: 0;
 }
```